# How to narrow down X axis date range in Power BI?

Tags: sql, graph, powerbi, visualization, line

[image: line graph in reference]

I am doing a line graph in Power BI for a value that has a date range of over 3 years. I have an issue where once it reaches a certain year, the line graph skips several values and then picks up on the next year. I want to be able to have a continuous line with accurate date ranges.

I tried editing the x-axis visualization but can't figure out how to exclude certain values/dates. As you can see in the image, the time period is listed in a weird format for some values, (20215000, 20225000). Any advice would be helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a Calendar/Date dimension? Normally, you put the date from the date dimension on your x-axis. If you wanted to filter down to just a subset of the entire calendar, you could add a "Between" slider to your canvas and filter down to the period of time you wanted to see in your graph/visual.

Comment: Hello. Thank you for commenting. I have a date dimension, but it is formatted in yyyymmdd instead of yyyy/mm/dd. I think I need to figure out how to change the data on that column to reflect a date and that may fix my problem.

Comment: Go into PowerQuery, and convert the column to a date, and you should be fine. No modification necessary.

Comment: I tried that method, and it gave me an error. I also tried to create a custom column with a custom formula - dateFormatted = Date(Left([date],4),Right(left([date],6),2),right([date],2)), and it did not pull in any data for my canvas.

Comment: I didn't use anything like that. I just clicked on the column as it was and converted it to a date, and it worked. Maybe it has to do with a local setting?

Comment: You were right! I had to change the date format to Swedish, and change it back to English again. It is working now. Thank you!!